# gnuplot 3d axis at the back

Tags: gnuplot

I need to draw a 3d axes gnuplot with the 0,0,0 at the back, NOT at the left as it currently is...
Any tip is welcome...
data file is like this:

```
0 0 0 1
0 .5 .5 1
0 1 1 2
1 1 1 3
```

i am using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
set xyplane 0
set xlabel 'X axis'
set ylabel 'Y axis' 
set zlabel 'Z axis' 
set ticslevel 0
set key center below
splot "data.txt" matrix  using 1:2:3  t "Data 1" w lines lc rgb "green",\
"" using 1:2:4  t "Data 2" w lines lc rgb "red"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clarify your question.  Normally you can rotate the result of an "splot" to any view angle you like.  (click and drag with left mouse button). When you reach an agreeable viewpoint, ask for a printout of the current view angles with "show view".   To reproduce the same view angle for later plots you can specify the saved angles before plotting.
E.g.

```
gnuplot> splot "MyFile"
### rotate with mouse to desired view ###
gnuplot> show view

        view is 63 rot_x, 60 rot_z, 1 scale, 1 scale_z
                 axes are independently scaled
                 azimuth 0

gnuplot> set view 63, 60
gnuplot> replot
```

Comment: Thanks, it is sooo easy :-) Just click on the graph and rotate anywhere... View also works...

Answer (score 0):

as an example:

> set view 65, 115

just experiment with different values